# how to use custom cell view class with search bar?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I am using search bar and display controller with my view controller. Everything is working  fine when i use default `UITableViewCell`. But when i use custom cell with controller . It doesn't display text on dragged label.

This code is working correct-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:  (NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"userName"];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Now i have assign that prototype cell with a class named `SearchFriendCell` and identifier `SearchFriends`. The `SearchFriendCell` Class contains a label with a outlet.
Now if i replace the above code with following Code , it doesn't show any result.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SearchFriends";
    SearchFriendCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[SearchFriendCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        cell.friendName.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"userName"];// this line doesn't work
    }

    return cell;
}
```

In the modified code if i replace commented line with following line, it display result-

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"userName"];
```

I don't know what is the problem here. Search bar display controller is not recognising my prototype cell. Before that i have used table view controller many times but i didn't get such type of problem.
Help me with some good answers.

Comment: did you connected `IBOutlet` of `friendName` in `SearchFriendCell`

Comment: What is friendName is it a UILabel or just NSString? is it added to the cell content view?

Comment: Is it a true prototype cell? Is `[SearchFriendCell alloc] initWithStyle:...` ever being called?

Comment: @Akhilrajtr yes i have connected friendName IBOutlet in SearchFriendCell.

Comment: @ahmedalkaff friendName is a UILabel

Comment: You have `if (cell==nil) {` - if the cell is registered properly (a true prototype) then you will always get a cell instance back from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` so you don't need to check. Verify this with debugging.

Comment: @Wain if i commented these lines , i gives error- 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cell is not registered properly. You say you have a prototype cell with the correct identifier but in the code you don't see an instance of the cell being created. This means that your code will run:

```
cell = [[SearchFriendCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

which will not create all of your subviews or connect any of the outlets.

You need to find out why your cell isn't registered properly. If you created it in a storyboard then it should be contained in the table view where it will be used (which should automatically register the cell). If you created it in a standalone XIB file then you need to load the NIB and register it explicitly when the table view is loaded.

---

You have 2 table views, the cell is registered with one but not the other - this is the way prototype cells work.

Your best options:

1. Remove the prototype cell, create an XIB and register the NIB with each table view explicitly
2. Not to use a search controller (so you only have 1 table view, manage the search bar yourself)

Comment: i have created it in storyboard above the table view. Yes i know it should be registered automatically. Don't know why it happening.

Comment: i have checked. If i use table view controller without search bar, it is working correct. But when i use it with search bar it is doesn't recognise.

Answer (score 4):

Your prototype cell is register in your tableview but in your search bar result tableview, when you call

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"SearchFriends";
    SearchFriendCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

you are using paramenter tableView that can be the search bar results tableview, which has no register for your custom prototype. So just change to

```
SearchFriendCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

You probably not need anymore

```
if (cell == nil) { ... }
```

best regards,
JL

Answer (score 0):

you need to create outlet and join it with your table view

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
```

and instead of using

```
SearchFriendCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

use

```
SearchFriendCell *cell = [self.myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```